# How to access recursive layers of custom layer in tensorflow keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

From tensorflow keras example. I can create a custom layer which contains Linear layer recursively

```py
class MLPBlock(layers.Layer):

  def __init__(self):
    super(MLPBlock, self).__init__()
    self.linear_1 = Linear(32)
    self.linear_2 = Linear(32)
    self.linear_3 = Linear(1)

  def call(self, inputs):
    x = self.linear_1(inputs)
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)
    x = self.linear_2(x)
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)
    return self.linear_3(x)
```

how do i access all the component layers of a custom layer, I want to access weight and biases of all the component layers.

ex:

```py
MLPBlock(Parent Layer):
    linear_1
    linear_2
    linear_3
```

I have looked into tensorflow keras api version r 1.14  https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras
but could not find any way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are following [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models). Based on that, here is how you can access the weights:

```
class MLPBlock(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MLPBlock, self).__init__()
        self.linear_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)
        self.linear_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)
        self.linear_3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.linear_1(inputs)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        x = self.linear_2(x)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        return self.linear_3(x)

mlp_block = MLPBlock()
y = mlp_block(tf.ones(shape=(3, 64)))
for layer in mlp_block.layers:
    weights, biases = layer.get_weights()
```

Please note that I slightly modified the example so that you can access the layer's weights and biases. Namely, what I did is instead of subclassing the class with `tf.keras.layers.Layer`, I subclassed with `tf.keras.Model` so that the stack of layers can be treated as a model, and then you can access the layers of that model. Then, instead of using the custom `Linear` layer, I used the `tf.keras.layers.Dense` for simplicity, however, using the custom layer should not make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wanted one more clarification.. In the tutorial it is mentioned.. Layers are recursively composable so I can make complex layers which is composition of layers. How can I access those member layers. And if I have complex model should I make my model as composition of sub models? and only use layers of abstraction for weights and biases.

Comment: Your intuition is right. If you have a complex model, than that is a composition of `tf.keras.Model` instances. You can access each of the member layers including their weights and biases easily.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Don't hesitate to mark the question as solved then.