# How to obtain all layers within a custom layer subclassed from keras.layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, keras-layer

I'm trying to get all layers from within a custom layer subclassed from tf.keras.layers but I am having difficulties with this. The end goal is to create a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) that has layers from tf.keras.layers.* Here is an example:

```
from tensorflow import keras
...

class ResidualBlock(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(
        self,
        filters0: int,
        filters1: int,
        activation: str = "leaky_relu",
        **kwargs,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.conv0 = keras.layers.Conv2D(
            filters0, 1, activation=activation, **kwargs)
        self.conv1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(
            filters1, 3, activation=activation,  **kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
        x = self.conv0(inputs, training=training)
        x = self.conv1(x, training=training)
        x = inputs + x
        return x

rb = ResidualBlock(2, 3)

new_model = Sequential([rb, keras.layers.Dense(200)])

convert_to_DAG(new_model)
```

I want to get something like this:

```
[{'type': 'ResidualBlock', 'children': ['conv2D_1']}, 
{'type': 'conv2D_1', 'children': ['conv2D_2', 'residual'}, 
{'type': 'conv2D_2', 'children': ['Dense_1']}, 
...
]
```

I've seen all related answers like:
[How to access recursive layers of custom layer in tensorflow keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479680/how-to-access-recursive-layers-of-custom-layer-in-tensorflow-keras)  which accesses layers from a model subclassed from tf Model, NOT tf layers.Layer

The following code from [Check which are the next layers in a tensorflow keras model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68126965/check-which-are-the-next-layers-in-a-tensorflow-keras-model) which breaks a model based on nodes but it does not recursively follow each layer to its base layer/operations (which I require).

```
def get_layer_summary_with_connections(layer, relevant_nodes): 
    info = {}
    connections = []
    for node in layer._inbound_nodes: 
        if relevant_nodes and node not in relevant_nodes:
            continue
        for inbound_layer, node_index, tensor_index, _ in node.iterate_inbound(): 
            connections.append(inbound_layer.name)
    name = layer.name
    info['type'] = layer.__class__.__name__
    info['parents'] = connections
    return info
```

The end result should be a DAG that contains all base layers + operations like this:
[DAG end result. All Layers are base layers + operations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g1pz.png)

Thank you for any help. I can clarify if anything is unclear

Comment: Do you need the ResidualBlock to be a layer class? I've looked at the code of ResNet and their block is a function which maps the residual connections. But they also use the functional API for that.

Comment: @mhenning yes, ideally inheriting from the layer class since many models have already been compiled using layers that subclass the layer class. In an ideal case, I could just expand layers recursively using `model.layers` but that is not possible in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`tf.Module.submodules`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Module#attributes:%7E:text=value%20to%20change.-,submodules,-Sequence%20of%20all), which should be a list of all `tf.Module`s that are attributes of the current module, and it searches recursively. Both `Layer` and `Model` inherit from `Module`.

In your case, try adding the following to list the submodules and confirm that the submodules of the `ResidualBlock` are indeed submodules of the model.

```py
print(new_model.submodules)
print(rb.submodules)

for rbs in rb.submodules:
    print("module: ", rbs, "isInModel?", rbs in new_model.submodules)
```

With this information it should be possible to create a DAG.

Comment: Thank you, but in this case, models subclassing keras.layers.* have already been instantiated and compiled. I would like to recursively follow the layers from layers.* subclassing, rather than module subclassing.

Comment: @HamzaKamran I'm not so sure about this instantiation issue, `rb.submodules` can list the submodules (which are typically layers) without having to be in a `Model`. On the other hand, after looking closely at the image in the question, is it possible that your goal is actually to connect not just the `Layer`s but also the operations in the computation graph? Because `residual` is not a `Layer` but a simple `Add` op.

Comment: yes, operations are another part along with the layers. This is difficult and perhaps requires another question. I might be able to get this from the computation graph but I'm not sure how to

Comment: yes operations are also required

Comment: @HamzaKamran In that case, I think we are getting closer to what tensorboard does. Perhaps this is another question about "how to parse TF computation graph"? I'm unfortunately not well-versed in that realm.